# Parse a TSV file

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I need to parse a file in TSV format (tab separated values). I use a regex to break down the file into each line, but I cannot find a satisfying one to parse each line.
For now I've come up this:

```
(?<g>("[^"]+")+|[^\t]+)
```

But it does not work if an item in the line has more than 2 consecutive double quotes.

Here's how the file is formatted: each element is separated by a tabulation. If an item contains a tab, it is encased with double quotes. If an item contains a double quote, it is doubled. But sometimes an element contains 4 conscutive double quotes, and the above regex splits the element into 2 different ones.

**Examples:**

> item1ok    "item""2""oK"

is correctly parsed into 2 elements: ***item1ok*** and ***item"2"ok*** (after trimming of the unnecessary quotes), but:

> item1oK    "item""""2oK"

is parsed into 3 elements: ***item1ok***, ***item*** and ***"2ok*** (after trimming again).

Has anyone an idea how to make the regex fit this case? Or is there another solution to parse TSV simply? (I'm doing this in C#).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx). This is technically a VB assembly, but you can use it even in C# by referencing the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` assembly.

The example at the link above even shows using it on a tab-separated file.

Comment: +1 It's part of the .Net framework: it's supported by Microsoft, it doesn't need separate deployment.

Comment: Just to be awere this is not usable in Dotnet Core and Dotnet Standard due to the VisualBasic code not being open sourced and not being ported.. ever.

Comment: @PiotrKula I  just create a project in vb.net in .net 6, I am able to use it.

Comment: Ahh cool in NET 6 it should be fine now because they implemented NetStandard 2.1 for almost all the code base. So that is awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Instead of trying to build your own CSV/TSV file parser (or using String.Split), I'd recommend you have a look at "[Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx)" or "[FileHelpers library](http://www.filehelpers.com/)".

I'm using the first one, and am very happy with it (it supports any separator characters, e.g. comma, semicolon, tab).

Comment: I've used the Lumenworks CSV reader, works well and would for a good base for a TSV reader.

Comment: That's surely a good solution, but I want to avoid additional dependencies to my code, so the .net class answer suits my needs better.

Comment: M4N, Lumenworks' CSV reader works well, except that it's getting confused between CSV and TSV (I think, anyways) on a specific line, since commas and quotes are on the same line or something. Do you know how to get it to only look at tabs for separation?

Comment: Disregard that, solved the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425800/quotes-in-tab-delimited-file/14200980#14200980

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using RegEx, maybe you could try the [String.Split Method (Char[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904305(VS.71).aspx)
 method.

Comment: String.Split() will consider encased tabulations as delimiters as well, so it's not correct.

Comment: I thought of that as soon as I hit the save button. What can I say? I know, I suck.