# Get numerical data from a tab-separated text file and store them in a list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a tab-separated text file like this:

```
customerNo  Offer   Score
1   1   0.273
2   1   0.630
3   1   0.105
4   1   0.219
5   1   0.000
6   1   0.303
7   1   0.760
```

I have a string array in my program that contains all the lines in this text file.
Using LINQ, I first would like to get rid of any lines that have non-numerical characters (like the header line above) or are empty and then would like to save the other lines as a List of Objects. Here my object would be something called `ScoreItem` that has properties: customerNo, Offer and Score. So eventually I get 7 of these objects from this file.

Comment: And where are you stuck at?

Comment: @AdrianCarneiro the LINQ query.

Comment: Would you care to share it so people can help?

Comment: @AdrianCarneiro share what? I don't know how to write it.

Comment: Consider to use existing readers (i.e. I believe CSVReader supports tab-delimited files [too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425800/quotes-in-tab-delimited-file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your very case I would do this:

```
File.ReadAllLines("the-file-full-path")
    .Select(x => x.Split('\t'))
    .Where(x =>
           {
               int i;
               return int.TryParse(x[0], out i);
           })
    .Select(x => new ScoreItem
                     {
                         CustomerNo = int.Parse(x[0]),
                         Offer = int.Parse(x[1]),
                         Score = double.Parse(x[2])
                     });
```

And consider using .ToArray() or .ToList() at the end to prevent possible reenumerations of that block in further code.

## Updated:

The code provided is straight-forward: it does not consider any additional checks for data format culture etc. To be sure the number are always parsed independently on current user's culture setup, for double parsing must be used `double.Parse(x[2], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` (for instance), instead.

Comment: thanks. looks great. will check first thing in the tomorrow and choose your answer if it worked.

Comment: That's obviously too straight forward as there are no any additional checks and all the file lines are look like the ones provided in the question. You can always correct that. But you better learn LINQ -- that's pretty simple question you are asking help for.

Comment: +1. Instead of not strictly functional call to `TryParse` you could have simply `Skip(1)` first line. Also consider specifying culture in parse calls so parsing `double` values does not depend on OP's location.

Comment: Note that calling `ToList` or `ToArray` is actually likely to be a pretty terrible idea here.  Processing a file very often means dealing with large amounts of data; being able to stream that data and not pull the entire file's contents into memory is a huge advantage, and one that basically comes for free when using LINQ; why throw it away needlessly?

Comment: Well, that always depends. But considering the user's level I would rather give him advice to be more careful rather with reenumerating. That's pretty common when new users just don't care of it. (But in our case we even have a 'situation' with I/O(!)).

Comment: @Agat So then state that you should be sure not to enumerate the sequence twice.  If he's doing that he should *not do that* rather than pulling everything into a list, in a context such as this.  It's the wrong solution to a problem you don't even know he has.

Comment: @Servy. I don't get your point. I might don't know what does the author of the question need, that's why I wrote "consider" instead of "must". But what I do know is that you can not know what is his idea for sure to give some such advice (unless he is just some his colleague or something).

Comment: @Agat Your "advice" is almost certainly likely to not be correct.  The situations in which it would be appropriate are very rare, the situations in which it would be wrong are quite common, as such it's not good advice to give, especially given that it doesn't explain it's advice effectively enough for the reader to determine if they should indeed follow it.

Comment: I guess, that's always a good approach to point users to **any other POSSIBLE** behaviours, and give then the ability to make final decisions. I don't see what's bothering you.

P.S. If the situation is very rare from your point of view, then... well... what can I say. It's not for me.

Comment: And I don't know why a question that created useful discussion had a vote down honestly.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm not always sure that it's only the first line that are headers. Maybe there's an extra line somewhere that will create problems.

Comment: @Agat I have used your LINQ query in my program but when I try to convert it to a list of my objects I get an error "Input string had an incorrect format." That's the translation of the error. Sorry my windows language is Swedish.

Comment: @Agat I cannot convert your LINQ to a list or array. It gives me a Format exception.

Comment: @Pedram As I mentioned, basicaly, the code does not check any culture checks etc. And the format exception occurs in your case as it expects '0,00' numbers with ',' delimiter (for your Swedish culture, I guess). So, I've applied an update to the answer which must work.

Comment: @Agat thank you so much. Working now! Had no idea Culture could have been this important.

Comment: @Pedram Culture *is really* important in many cases of .NET development. That's just a simple example of how it influences numbers parsing or formatting.